# Sublime Text 3 Emmet triggering conflict?

Tags: css, text-editor, sublimetext3, emmet

I just started using Sublime Text 3 beta. Love it so much.

And I love using Emmet while coding.

But there's one thing annoys me that whenever I am editing CSS for example, code suggest interrupts so my trigger key(which is Tab key) won't work. (I have to hit Enter key instead).

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: FYI, that is known as "intellisense" :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

Changing a line in key binding file from:

```
{ "keys": ["enter"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
```

to:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "commit_completion", "context":
```

that worked for me.

I go for this for the time being. I still want other suggestion though.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

The third version is not yet stable (only beta). You can report the problem [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=3)

Answer (score 0):

Emmet parses abbreviations in real time but Sublime Text does not provide API to correctly override native snippets. So there are might be some quirks when expanding abbreviations by Tab key.

You may want to disable `disable_tab_abbreviations_on_auto_complete` preference to make Tab key exclusive for Emmet: https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime/blob/master/Preferences.sublime-settings#L29

But you will not be able to use native snippets in HTML and CSS anymore.