# sublime text 3 and emmet not completing

Tags: sublimetext3, emmet, tab-completion

I have sublime text 3 and emmet and am trying to use Emmet but a few things are broken/ I am using  completion.

**ul+< tab >**

gives

```
<ul>
</ul>
```

Also

```
input:text
```

outputs

```
inupt:<table></table>
```

Is sublime hijacking the the  completion.

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196983/sublime-text-3-emmet-triggering-conflict

Comment: @SergeyChikuyonok there don't appear to be any good answers to that question, though, otherwise I'd close it...

Comment: The answer is wether you’re trying to expand with Tab when autocomplete popup is visible or not

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, Sublime Text hides the completion popup by default when working in the `text` scope. The scope for HTML is `text.html`, so that behaviour is inherited. Add the `text` (or `text.html`) scope to `auto_complete_selector` in your user settings. Now, when you type code, you should see a completion popup, that allows you to select different types of completion. Personally, I have Emmet and the HTML5 package installed, so when typing `ul` I'm seeing two completion entries to choose from. I suspect that you're triggering the wrong completion.

The HTML5 package completes `ul` to `<ul>|</ul>`, while Emmet completes to `<ul><li>|</li></ul>` (over multiple lines.)

So, theree might indeed be another package interfering with Emmet. The completion popup should make it easier to see if that's the case. Otherwise, you will have to disable all your packages to narrow down the problem.