# Emmet not works in .js file in Sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, sublimetext3, sublimetext, emmet

I want to add `.addEventListener` but it doesn't work in Sublime text 3
[image: addEventListener]

I tried install JavaScript Completions but it suggest over much suggestions and I have lags with it also it autocomplets with a lot of atributes which I don't need
I tried to set setting

```json
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript":"javascriptreact"
    }
```

And

```
{
        "keys": ["tab"],
        "command": "emmet_expand_abbreviation",
        "args": { "tab": true },
        "context": [
            { "key": "emmet_abbreviation" },
            { "key": "emmet_tab_expand" },
            { "key": "num_selections", "operand": 1 }
        ]
    },
```

This question is not a duplicate of [Sublime Text 3 Emmet triggering conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23196983/sublime-text-3-emmet-triggering-conflict) or [sublime text 3 and emmet not completing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32965359/sublime-text-3-and-emmet-not-completing) because I am asking here about it not working in `.js` file only (I haven't problems with `.html` or `.css` files)

Comment: Have you considered using [`LSP`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) and the [`LSP-typescript`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-typescript) helper package? It also does straight JS as well as TS and JSX.

Comment: Yeh it helps    111

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+shift+p` - install package
LSP
`ctrl+shift+p` - install package
LSP Typescript

Note:node.js required (note win8.1+ required)